# Clojure: using library functions from REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I've just started with Clojure and have never used Java

I understood how to create and run a leiningen project from terminal, but I can't understand how to load libraries in REPL before running commands.

I'm trying to build a simple web scrapler with clj-webdriver; my original file looks like this

```
(ns prova.core (:gen-class))

(use 'clj-webdriver.taxi)

(set-driver! {:browser :firefox})

(defn -main
  [& args]

  (to "https://github.com/login")

  (input-text "#login_field"  "email")
  (input-text "#password"     "psw")

  (click "input[name='commit']")

)
```

The closest I (think) have got to achieve it was going into the webdriver src folder and try this command

```
penta@laptop:~/clj-webdriver-master/src/clj_webdriver$ clojure
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> (use 'taxi)
```

but it returned

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate taxi__init.class or taxi.clj on classpath: clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:432)
```

even thou in the same folder the file taxy.clj was indeed present.

So, what is the procedure to run a REPL that can make use of a library functions?

Many thanks

Comment: Just as a note, if you only want to try a library without creating a project you can use [lein-try](https://github.com/rkneufeld/lein-try). A very cool leiningen plug-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [leiningen](http://leiningen.org) build tool, install it according to the website's instructions and make a new project.

```
lein new myproject
cd myproject
```

Then edit `project.clj` in which you add clj-webdriver as a dependency:

```
(defproject myproject "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [clj-webdriver "0.6.0"]])
```

Then type `lein repl` and a REPL will spin up with clj-webdriver on the classpath. You should now be able to continue as you did in your example.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks! For other noobies like me: after you did "lenin repl" (where usually you would do "lenin run"), the REPL will execute all the code before the "defn -main" so now it's like you're typing and executing the main function line by line. You can also copy/paste multiple line and they'll be processed in sequence.

Comment: Top level expressions are always evaluated when the code is loaded and shouldn't contain side effects in general. Put them inside functions and call them from the REPL.